# Shuffle a deck of 7 different cards (labeled 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).

Tags: probability

Shuffle a deck of 7 different cards (labeled 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). Choose 4 of them in order and observe the sequence. How many possible sequences are there?

Comment: $\binom74\cdot4!$

Answer (score 2):

We have $7$ choices for the first card, $6$ remaining choices for the second, $5$ remaining for the third, and $4$ remaining for the fourth.  This means that there are $7*6*5*4 = 840$ possible sequences.